# how to store bitcoin and other currencies in mysql database

Tags: mysql, decimal, currency, bitcoin

I try to make payment system. Customers can make purchases with bitcoin or other curriencies like (USD,EUR) i have a decimal amount column with (16,8), for bitcoin amounts it works normally, but when i try to put usd value for example 100 usd , it becomes 100.00000000 , my question is should store amount like this ? use same decimal column for bitcoin and other currencies? is it bad for performance when counting all records? or should i have multiple column for bitcoin decimal(16,8) and for other currencies decimal(10,2) , show me a way - please consider millions of records when you answering.

Comment: This is just a cosmetic one... Use `10,8` as you need it for BitCoin but when displaying USD and EUR, etc, please use your programming language to strip the redundant zeroes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two aspects of performance -- speed and space.  Speed is usually not a concern because fetching rows is far more costly than the effort to manipulate decimal/double/etc.  Space can be a concern (and lead to slowdowns) if you are talking about a billion rows.

Rule of Thumb:  `DECIMAL(m,n)` take about `m/2` bytes.  In the case of `(16,8)`, it takes exactly 8 bytes.

`DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `BIGINT`: 8 bytes.  Etc.

Don't use `VARCHAR` for numeric values, especially if you need to sort them.

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` incur an extra rounding (decimal to/from binary), leading to possible round-off errors, especially when adding up lots of numbers.

I don't know for sure, 8 decimal places is the official max needed for Bitcoin, and is more than enough for any other currency.  4 is the most I have heard of for a currently used currency.  (Pounds/Shillings/Pence is no longer in use.)

`DECIMAL(16,8)` overflows at 100,000,000 dollars/euros/whatever.  Make sure that is enough.  `DECIMAL(17,8)` also takes 8 bytes, giving you a Billion max.  So you may as well use 17 instead of 16.

Back to the question...  There is no 'perfect' answer.